# My server is never used to receive emails (only send) how to block all postfix connection or spam attempt?

Tags: debian, postfix

In the syslog file (debian) I have thousand lines like :

```
Dec  3 10:38:59 vps277777 postfix/smtpd[593]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:12301: Connection refused
Dec  3 10:39:00 vps277777 postfix/smtpd[593]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.234.216.87]
Dec  3 10:39:00 vps277777 postfix/smtpd[593]: disconnect from unknown[185.234.216.87] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Dec  3 10:39:00 vps277777 postfix/smtpd[593]: connect from unknown[185.234.216.87]
Dec  3 14:28:31 vps277777 postfix/anvil[6292]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:27.100.26.165) at Dec  3 14:22:10
Dec  3 14:28:31 vps277777 postfix/anvil[6292]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:27.100.26.165) at Dec  3 14:22:10
Dec  3 14:28:31 vps277777 postfix/anvil[6292]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Dec  3 14:22:10
```

Each day.

My server is never used to receive emails. So there should be no connection from outside. How to block everything?

Comment: Cf. ["In postfix, how could I disable incoming mail?"](https://superuser.com/questions/430023/in-postfix-how-could-i-disable-incoming-mail).

Comment: @ Piotr P. Karwasz : thank you. I am trying.